# According to Rambam, where do the souls of the righteous dwell in the period between the death of their bodies and the resurrection?

Tags: rambam, death, soul, afterlife

I am an Italian Noahide.

If I have understood correctly, Rambam affirms that the resurrection of the dead is reserved only for the righteous, who, after being resurrected, will live a long and joyful life at the end of which they will die again; after this second bodily death, they will definitively enter into  the World to Come, which is a kingdom of only souls.

Then,according to Rambam,where do the souls of the righteous dwell in the period between the death of their bodies and the resurrection?

Answer (score 3):

The same place. The Rambam only recognises two worlds, this world, which includes era of Moshiach, and Olam Haba (i.e. Olam HaNeshamot, Gan Eden). Souls without bodies exist in the latter, before they come to the world, after they die, and ultimately forever after the period of Moshiach is complete.

As Rambam states in [Hilchos Teshuva 8:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Repentance.8.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> They only called it “The World to Come” because it is the Life which comes to a person after the life of this World, where we exist in body and soul, and which comes to each person at first.

I know you didn't ask this but for others reading this answer, one should be aware that this is a machlokes in the gemara, and the Arizal, who held by the opinion that Olam Haba is here, after Moshiach and a rectification of the world, has ruled for us and all major authorities accept this as psak, e.g. Tanya and Derech Hashem who are the seminal philosophy treatises of the Chassidish and Litvish worlds respectively (see Igros Kodesh of the Lubavitcher Rebbe, Vol. I, p. 142, foot note 1, and Sanhedrin 91b; see also Ritva on Rosh HaShanah 16b).

Comment: could you point to exactly where I can find this in derech hashem?

Comment: @Dude See 1:3:10, 1:4:2.